# Do upgrade card effects stack in SteamWorld Quest?

Tags: steamworld-quest

If I use two copies of an upgrade card on a single character in one turn, will the card effect stack?

For example, Mana Barrier grants one ally a Damage Shield equal to 20% of their maximum Health for up to three turns. If I use Mana Barrier on the same ally twice, will their shield equal 40% of their health or will it be capped to 20%?

What about Bravado? The description states it will raise Armilly's Strength by one grade for three turns. Will her strength be raised two grades if I use the card twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, same cards doesn't stack effects. However, different cards with the same effect will stack. Have this in mind to avoid reusing repeated cards.

For example: if you use **Bravado** twice, second one won't do anything extra, but if you use **Bravado** and **Aspiring Hero** will give the two strength increases.

*Source: Tested InGame*